# Division in rings: for any two elements $a$ and $b$, we can have $a=bq+r$, where $0\leq r<b$. How?

Tags: ring-theory

How can $r$ satisfy this inequality when no assumptions of the ring being ordered have been made? This concept has been confusing me for some time now. Let's suppose the ring is not ordered. How can we ever ascertain if $r$ is bigger or smaller than $b$?
Going by my understanding, in a non-ordered ring, for to elements $a$ and $b$, there can be $|R|$ different ways of writing $a=bq+r$, where obviously $q$ and $r$ take different values.

Comment: @George L.- Thanks for the edits :)

Answer (score 3):

When the Division Algorithm is abstracted to a general [Euclidean domain,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) the hypothesis on the remainder $\rm\:r\:$ is not that $\rm\:0\le r < b\:$ but, rather, that $\rm\:r = 0\:$ or $\rm\:f(r) < f(b),\:$  for some fixed "size" map $\rm\: f\ :\ R\backslash\{0\} \to \Bbb N\ $ (or any well-ordered set).

For example, in $\rm\:\Bbb Z\:$ one has $\rm\:f(r) = |r|\:$ and in $\rm\:K[x]\:$ one has $\rm\:f(p) = deg(p).$